# Unnecessary Duplicates BeautifulSoup For Loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nested-loops

With the following code, I am able to extract the location type (hospital, urgent care, etc), the name of the location, and its address.  I am, however, presented with a bunch of duplicates.  How can I get rid of the duplicates and only keep one record of each location?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

file = open("/home/daniel/Downloads/wellstar.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(file,"html.parser")

types = soup.findAll("h3",class_="WebFont SpotBodyGreen")
names = soup.findAll("div",class_="PurpleBackgroundHeading")
addresses = soup.findAll("div",class_="WS_Location")

locations_saved=""
for type in types:
   locations=""
    for name in names:
        for address in addresses:
            locations=locations+"\n"+type.text+name.text+address.text
locations_saved=locations_saved+"\n"+locations[1:]
print(locations_saved)
```

Comment: Use a set to store the data and then write the content

Comment: Do you have an example of how to loop through the set?

Comment: Where you are concatenating just set.add